# Git server-side pre-receive hook

Tags: bash, git, server-side, devops, githooks

I am working on enforcing git pre-commit hook as a server-side pre-receive or an update hook and unable to find proper examples on achieving it.

I was able to successfully implement/test the pre-commit hook

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running pre-commit hook" 
checks=($APPSETTING_DEVPASSWORD $APPSETTING_DEVUSER $APPSETTING_DEVPASS_ELMAH) # create an array

git diff --cached --name-status | while read flag file; do
    if [ "$flag" == 'D' ]; then continue; fi

for word in ${checks[@]}
do
    if egrep -q "$word" "$file"; then
        echo "ERROR: Disallowed expression \"${word}\" in file: ${file}" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
done
```

I am trying to translate the same into server-side hook where the hook should look for the checks array and exit with 1 if the diff contains the values in the checks array.

> Information Found online

Bitbucket server contains only the base repository and doesn't contain the files from the local repository, Hence the diff of the commit sha needs to be evaluated while pushing.

Can someone please help translate the same into a server-side git hook.

Comment: Where is your git server?  Is it on a host you maintain, or are you using a service like github, bitbucket, etc?

Comment: It is a self hosted Bitbucket instance